# View changing on UITableView update

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uipickerview

I have a rather complex form being laid out in a `UITableView`. This form has some `UICollectionView` inside a table view cell and also some pickers that show up the same way it does on Calendar app:

[image]

Now when I do this on my app, one of the `UICollectionView` I have gets taller than how it started - and it keeps going (I added a red border to make sure it was the `UICollectionView` that was being resized):

[image]

I tried debugging the `UICollectionView` view property but it never changes (and it's getter/setter aren't called more than what I expected) - even though when I print it on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it does shows up resized. Is there any way I can debug this better, or have someone been at the same situation?

Thanks!

Code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//self.campos is a dictionary with sections and rows stored
    NSMutableArray *infoCampos = [[self.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"campos"];
NSDictionary *infoCampo = [infoCampos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([[infoCampo objectForKey:@"nome"] isEqualToString:@"dosePorComprimido"]) {
    //Remove picker cell if finds it
    for (infoCampo in infoCampos) {
        if ([infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"] == self.dosagemMedicamento.view) {
            [infoCampos removeObject:infoCampo];
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }

    //Insert new cell
    infoCampo = [infoCampos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [infoCampos addObject:@{@"tipo":@5, @"view":self.dosagemMedicamento.view, @"nome":[infoCampo objectForKey:@"nome"]}];
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.dosagemMedicamento.view.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[pickerDosagem]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"pickerDosagem":self.dosagemMedicamento.view}]];
}
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *infoCampo = [[[self.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"campos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIView *view;

    if ([infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"]) {
        view = (UIView *) [infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"];
        return view.frame.size.height;
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSMutableDictionary *infoCampo = [[[self.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"campos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIView *view;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[[infoCampo objectForKey:@"nome"] stringByAppendingString:@"ViewLinhaCellView"] forIndexPath:indexPath];

        view = [cell viewWithTag:1];

        [view addSubview:[infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"]];

return cell;
}
```

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that I'm not updating the table view with reloadData but only the needed sections/rows with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and reloadSections. So that makes it even weirder because I'm not reloading that particular section.

**EDIT 2:** added data source e delegate code

Comment: post your table view data source codes. its seems to be u returning wron height fot that cell. check your heightforcell method and be sure your returning proper value for that cell

Comment: I know that - my heighForRowAtIndexPath only returns the subview height, so the problem is that this subview (the UICollectionView) is being resized and so is the cell.

Comment: Can you post code? It's going to be very hard to say what's wrong without a code sample.

Comment: @Austin which method specifically? There a lot of classes involved in this screen so it would be hard to paste everything there.

Comment: I think that the table view data source / delegate code would be most relevant

Comment: @Austin done! Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here, in the implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *infoCampo = [[[self.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"campos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIView *view;

    if ([infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"]) {
        view = (UIView *) [infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"];
        return view.frame.size.height;
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
```

The view is probably getting resized by auto layout or its autoresizing mask. There isn't enough info here to say exactly why, but table views and auto layout can have some funny behavior. I recommend just returning a height that you set, rather than getting the height from the view:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *infoCampo = [[[self.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"campos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIView *view;

    if ([infoCampo objectForKey:@"view"]) {
        if ([infoCampo objectForKey:@"viewHeight"]) {
            return [[infoCampo objectForKey:@"viewHeight"] floatValue];
        } else {
            return 216.0f;
        }
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
```

The `viewHeight` key allows you to specify a custom height for each cell's view, but this implementation also returns a default height (216) that happens to be the standard height for picker views.

Comment: Great idea, Austin. I think I might go with that, even though I would love to know the reason of the resizing. Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion to check, if the view is loaded from a nib: when you create a nib, the view has an autoresizing mask set, even if the nib is using auto layout. Try setting the view's `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`.

Comment: Even though I'm not loading it from a nib, setting that property solved! You rock! But could you elaborate more on how does the autoresizingMask work? Why is it influenced by the UITableView reload? Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help. The mask is simply a set of flags indicating whether you want the view to grow or shrink with its superview. It is influenced by the reload because the table view probably resized the cell that it contained, causing it to grow.